# Galois group for splitting field of $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt2}$ and $\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $\mathbf F = \mathbb Q(\omega)$, where $\omega = e^{2\pi i \over
> > 3}$, determine galois group for splitting field of
> $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt2}$ and $\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]2}$ over F

My solution is:

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt2}$ and $\alpha' = \sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt2}$ and $\alpha_1 ... \alpha_6 = \alpha, \alpha', \omega\alpha, \omega\alpha', \omega^2\alpha, \omega^2\alpha'$

I can easily determine the splliting fiel $\mathbf K = \mathbf F(\alpha, \alpha', \omega\alpha, \omega\alpha', \omega^2\alpha, \omega^2\alpha')$ and $\alpha$ has order 6 over F.

The order of Galois group is 6 or 18 which is determine by whehter $\alpha' \subset  \mathbf F(\alpha)$
There is only two of 6 group: $S_3$ and $C_6$
For order 18 group as transitive subgroups of $S_6$ is $S_3 \times C_3$
As I do not know which is the Galois group, I choose subgroup (12)(34)(56) which belong all of them, which is fix $\alpha^3 \subset \mathbf Q(\sqrt2)$ and $\alpha\alpha' \subset \mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ The fix field $\mathbf Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt[3]2)$ has six order over $\mathbf Q$ so the Galois group must >12 = 6 * 2 so it is the $S_3 \times C_3$

Is ths analysis correct?

I want to use this same to determine
Let $\beta = \sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]2}, \beta' = \sqrt{2+\omega\sqrt[3]2}, \beta'' = \sqrt{2+\omega^2\sqrt[3]2}$ and $\beta_1 ... \beta_6 = \beta, \beta', \beta'', -\beta, -\beta', -\beta''$ which Galois group has order 6,12 and 24.

Is there any better solution, this should be a lot if information about the group of order 6,12,18 and 24 and transitive subgroups of $S_6$

Comment: For $\alpha$ the splitting field is of degree $18$ over $F$, splitting field being $F(\alpha, \sqrt [3]{2})$ so the Galois group is of order $18$ as well.

Comment: For $\alpha=\root3\of{2+\sqrt2}$ we are looking at the splitting field of the minimal polynomial $f(x)=x^6-4x^3+2$, irreducible by Eisenstein. I think $\alpha'\notin\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$, as $\alpha\alpha'=\root3\of2$. This suggests to me that $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\alpha'):\Bbb{Q}]=18$,and, consequently, the splitting field of $f(x)$ is a degree $36$ extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: This is corroborated by an application of Dedekind's theorem (using factorizations of $f(x)$ modulo various primes). There are elements of orders two and three with different cycle types in the Galois group (over the rationals), so the Sylow groups have orders at least $4$ and $9$ respectively. On the other hand, you identified the zeros of $f(x)$, so it is obvious that the extension degree cannot be higher than $36$.

Comment: So I agree with @ParamanandSingh. Over $F$ the splitting field has degree $18$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh,@JyrkiLahtonen, Here are some question, that how could we make sure that $\sqrt [3]{2} \notin F(\alpha)$, and Even we know the order of group, how to decide which it is?

Comment: One can use field trace to show that $\sqrt[3]{2}\notin F(\alpha) $.

Comment: Using algebraic number theory we could argue as follows. Modulo seven $\sqrt2=\pm3$. Then $2+3$ is not a cubic residue modulo seven, but $2-3\equiv3^3$ is. Therefore there is a difference between $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$. If I think of a simpler way, I will say more.

Comment: The same with Dedekind: Modulo $7$ we have $f(x)=(x+1)(x+2)(x+4)(x^3+2)$, so there is a 3-cycle in the Galois group over $\Bbb{Q}$, but also a product of two disjoint 3-cycles, because modulo five $f(x)$ is irreducible, giving us a 6-cycle, and as its square the desired product of two disjoint 3-cycles.

Comment: For order 18 group, we remove the two group has $C_9$ as it not inside $S_6$. So its must contain $C_3 \times C_3$. But without information about $S_6$. We still cannot figure out which is the Galois group.

Comment: I seem to have explained how to find the Galois group of this polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2072301/11619). I did use my "go to"-technique of Dedekind's theorem. Finding the subgroup fixing $F$ should not be too difficult.

Comment: It may be possible to cook up an alternative approach starting from the (brute forced) calculation that $\alpha+\alpha'$ is a root of the polynomial
$$g(x)=x^9-12x^6-6x^3-64.$$ Mathematica says $g(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$, so we get nine as a factor of $[K:F]$. But I don't see a paper and pencil of proving that yet :-)

Comment: Anyway, this is close to being a duplicate of that. I won't vote that way (without consulting others) as my vote would be immediately binding (I have earned three applicable dupehammers). Also, I'm very reluctant to use a question I answered myself as duplicate target unless the duplication is clear cut, which is not the case here.

Comment: In fact, in the other thread Pierre-Guy Plamondon does exactly that! Though he glosses over irreducibility of $g(x)$. If you have not heard of Dedekind's theorem, I recommend you study that answer instead.

Comment: I haven't thought it through, but looking at factorizations of $h(x)=(x^2-2)^3-2$ modulo various primes I suspect the splitting field over $\Bbb{Q}$ to have degree $24$. So degree $12$ over $F$.

Comment: Thanks, Jyrki, I do not know the Dedekind theorem, But the refer question sure be the result for me. I would try it for the $\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K=\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2})$. Every algebraic integer of $K$ is of the form $p+q\sqrt {2}$ with $p, q$ as integers. Let us observe that the numbers $$a=\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt {2}},b=\sqrt [3]{2-\sqrt {2}},c=ab=\sqrt [3]{2},d=b/a=\sqrt [3]{3-2\sqrt{2}}$$ are all algebraic integers (as they are cube roots of algebraic integers in $K$). We show that none of them lie in $K$.
If $a\in K$ then $$2+\sqrt{2}=(p+q\sqrt{2})^3$$ which implies $$2-\sqrt{2}=(p-q\sqrt {2})^3$$ and then multiplying these equations we get $$2=(p^2-2q^2)^3$$ which is absurd as $2$ is not a cube of an integer. Similarly we can show that $b\notin K, c\notin K$.

If $d\in K$ then $$3-2\sqrt{2}=(p+q\sqrt {2})^3$$ which implies $$3=p^3+6pq^2,3p^2q+2q^3=-2$$
Then $p\mid 3,q\mid 2$ and thus $$p=\pm 1,\pm 3,q=\pm 1,\pm 2$$ and none of the combinations satisfy the equations so that $d\notin K$.

Since $a, b, c, d$ are cube roots of algebraic integers in $K$ each of them is of degree $3$ over $K$. We now show that $b\notin K(a) $. To that end let us use the trace map $\text{tr} \, :K(a, b) \to K$ and let $[K(a, b) :K] =n$.

If $b\in K(a) $ then $$b=p+qa+ra^2$$ for some $p, q, r\in K$. The numbers $a, b, c, d$ as well as their squares are real radicals over $K$ and hence their trace is $0 $. Applying the trace map on this equation we get $$0=np+q\cdot 0+r\cdot 0$$ ie $p=0$ and then $$c=ab=qa^2+ra^3$$ Applying trace map again we get $$0=q\cdot 0+nra^3$$ as $ra^3\in K$ so that $r=0$. We then have $b=qa$ or $d=q\in K$ which is already proved to be false. This contradiction shows that $b\notin K(a) $. It then follows that $c\notin K(a), d\notin K(a) $.

Since the numbers $b, c, d$ are cube roots of some numbers lying in $K$ (and therefore in $K(a) $) it follows that each of them is of degree $3$ over $K(a)$. Let $M=K(a, b) $ and then $[M:K] =9$ and then $[M:\mathbb{Q}] =18$ and since $M\subseteq \mathbb{R} $ it follows that $[M(\omega) :M] =2$ ie $[M(\omega) :\mathbb{Q}] =36$.

In other words $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt {2},\omega,a,b)$ is of degree $36$ over rationals and then $F(\sqrt{2},a,b)$ is of degree $18$ over $F$. Since $\sqrt{2}\in F(a) $ we can write the same field as $F(a, b) $.

This field $F(a, b) $ contains all roots of the polynomial $f(x) =(x^3-2)^2-2$ and is the splitting of $f(x) $ over $F$ and is of degree $18$ over $F$. Since $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ its Galois group must be transitive and as you mention in your post the desired group is $S_3\times C_3$. However it would be nice to know the individual automorphisms of $F(a, b) $ fixing $F$.

Comment: Interesting use of the trace. I think it is correct, but I don't recall having seen the technique before! Then again, my recollection is no longer what it was at some point in my life :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I got the technique from discussion in comments (by orangeskid) below this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4251890/72031